# saving data in between pages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have been reading about JSF navigation between pages in an application and I am still a little bit confused. I have a small web application with a series of pages with continue and previous buttons on each page. To save the valid data entered on the view, I am trying to figure out ways to make the valid form data stick when the user goes back and forward. Initially, I had the page views in session scope but I understood that its bad practice. The data that I am capturing can be a managed bean with composite objects within the bean that corresponds to the data that is captured in the pages. But, I read that managed bean in session is not a good idea either. After reading through so many posts, I feel that I should know the solution but its still not very clear as to how to save the validated data into JSF so that it displays when the user navigates back and forth? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Look at the 'deltaspike' viewaccessscope. It sounds like it is the solution for you

Comment: @ Kukeltje, at this time, its hard for us to consider a new framework but I am glad to know there are options available. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you're trying to accomplish some kind of wizard-like navigation. For this use-case I would suggest the use of a `@ConversationScoped` backend Bean.

This scope is not provided by the JSF- but by the CDI-framework which just work perfectly together.

To get this to work you essentially have to follow these steps:

1. Create a CDI Bean like:

   ```
   @Named   
   @ConversationScoped    
   public class MyBean implements Serializable {    
     @Inject    
     private Conversation conversation;    
     ...
   }
   ```

   `@Named` is the CDI alternative to JSFs `@ManagedBean`.
   Your class should implement the `Serializable` interface to be able to passivate its state.
   CDI `@Inject` the Conversation-object to use in your code.
2. Start the conversation anywhere inside your code via:

   ```
   conversation.start();
   ```
3. Do your magic: process input, change data, navigate, persist to db,...
4. End the conversation (in your case at the last page, maybe after a click on a 'Finish'-Button)

   ```
   conversation.end();
   ```

A quick google search came up with this pretty tutorial implementing a questionaire site which could be useful to you. Have a look at [this](http://javabeat.net/jsf-2-conversationscoped/).

Hope this helps. Have fun!

Comment: Read about the 'viewaccessscope' I referred to above. It can, in many cases be used instead of a conversationscoped bean in a more simple way. In more complex situations conversationscoped would indeed maybe be better

Comment: @kukeltje: maybe you're right but its hard to say without knowing the exact structure of OP's code. I suggested the  `@ConversationScoped` because it comes out-of-the-box with any JEE server while DeltaSpike would be a additional dependency. Cheers!

Comment: @Jasper: Thank you so much for this suggestion. This will definitely work for the wizard style flow that I am looking at.

Comment: it was a suggestion by @SimonSez, not jasperdevries ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not persisting the data to a database? If so, you can use a request-scoped managed bean, that way when you navigate back to the original page the updated records will be re-retrieved from the database and your changes will be displayed.

Comment: we have constraints that we cannot save this data into the database till the user submits the final form page from a timeline perspective.